# Is there an easy way to wrap C# interfaces in inheriting libraries?

Tags: c#

For example, there's a `ThirdPartyLibrary` containing lots of interfaces. I create a wrapping library for specific purposes, and I only need `Interface1`, `Interface2` and `Interface3`, which I will pass on to users.

My library will have `PrivateAssets="all"`, so users can't use the "non-public" libraries.

Now, I have two choices:

1. Copy each interface individually, e.g. `IMyInterface` : `IThirdPartyInterface`
2. The user downloads `ThirdPartyLibrary` to access `IThirdPartyInterface`

Option 1 sounds painful, and I don't want the user to download `ThirdPartyLibrary` in option 2 and get exposed to all the things they don't need.

Is there a way to simply list what I need to carry over to a new namespace?

```
Using ThirdPartyLibrary.Extra.Things.Required;

ThirdPartyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface1 : MyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface1
ThirdPartyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface2 : MyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface2
ThirdPartyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface3 : MyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface3
```

Comment: No, there is no simple fix for this. You either inherit your own interfaces from theirs, and that will bring over the dependency on the 3rd party assembly as well and expose everything in there anyway, or if you want to truly hide this 3rd party library code-wise, you will need to make your own classes exposed using your own interfaces, which inside map to calls to the third party objects.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to expose to your library's callers only your interfaces, and not those of your dependencies.

Just expose your interfaces that inherit from theirs, exposing all its public members to your callers:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public interface MyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface1 : ThirdPartyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface1 { }
    public interface MyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface2 : ThirdPartyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface2 { }
    public interface MyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface3 : ThirdPartyLibrary.Interfaces.Interface3 { }
}
```

But if your library truly is a wrapper library, you probably don't want this, because now if ThirdPartyLibrary updates one of its interfaces, yours will be changed as well.

Comment: I guess that's the tradeoff, depending on how closely I want to follow ThirdPartyLibrary functionality? If I update ThirdPartyLibrary, my interfaces might be incompatible anyway.